# Как получить разницу во времени при помощи библиотеки Luxon.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть входящее значение в формате `ISO`, например `2021-01-26T21:11:13.000000Z` (дата в прошлом). Мне надо получить разницу между настоящей датой и датой в прошлом, которая будет выражаться в днях, часах и минутах, **используя библиотеку `luxon`**.

```
const d1 = DateTime.local() // current date
const d2 = DateTime.fromISO(updatedAt) // past date
const d3 = Interval.fromDateTimes(d2, d1).length() // 778620597
```

Посредством этого кода получается получить разницу в миллисекундах, но перевести в дни, часы и минуты не получается. В конечном итоге нужно получить объект с разницей во времени и вывести строку в виде `"В ожидании 0 дней, 2 часа, 36 минут"`.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, библиотека Luxon не умеет приводить интервалы в человекочитаемый вид. Всё, что мне удалось, это вывести объект

```
const d3 = Interval.fromDateTimes(d2, d1).toDuration(["days", "hours", "minutes"]).values
```

Чтобы получить интервал в читаемом виде можно использовать библиотеку [humanize-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration).